# How to get an Http response code in a soap client?

Tags: java, spring, cxf, cxf-client

There is a soap web service and a client. Uses the Apache CXF / Spring bundle.
Client:

```
public class MyWebServiceClientFactoryCXF {
    public MyWebServiceAPI getMyWebServiceClient(String URI, String username, String password) throws MalformedURLException {
        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setServiceClass(MyWebServiceAPI.class);
        factory.setAddress(URI);
        factory.setUsername(username);
        factory.setPassword(password);
        factory.setDataBinding(new AegisDatabinding());
        return (MyWebServiceAPI) factory.create();
    }
}
```

Spring context:

```
<bean id="myWebServiceClientFactory" class="mypakg.MyWebServiceClientFactoryCXF"/>
<bean id="myWebServiceClient" factory-bean="myWebServiceClientFactory" factory-method="getMyWebServiceClient">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="${ws.url}"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" type="java.lang.String" value="${ws.login}"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" type="java.lang.String" value="${ws.pwd}"/>
</bean>
```

Uses:

```
public class App {
    @Autowired
    private MyWebServiceAPI wsClient;

    public void someMethod() {
        wsClient.getSomeInfo();
        // Need to know http response code from `wsClient.getSomeInfo()`
    }
}
```

How can I get the response code from the soap web service?
I can specify an interceptor for `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean`, but how can I pass the value from interceptor to the `App.someMethod()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following piece of code:

```
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;


    public void someMethod() {
        try {
            wsClient.getSomeInfo(); //exception here for non-2xx http status by default
        } finally {
           Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(wsClient);
           Integer responseCode = client.getResponseContext().get(Message.RESPONSE_CODE);  
        }
```

See also:

[ClientProxy javadoc](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/frontend/ClientProxy.html)

[Client javadoc](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/endpoint/Client.html)